# Error in compiling D-ITG

Tags: mingw, distributed, traffic

i have try to compile D-ITG (Distributed Internet Traffic Generator ) on a windows
but i get this errors:
common.mk:5: recipe for target 'common/ITG.o' failed
common.mk:5: recipe for target 'common/thread.o' failed

in instruction manual said follow this steps
1. download and unpack the ”D-ITG-2.8.1-r2058M-src.zip” package somewhere on your filesystem;
2. from the command line, enter the ”D-ITG-2.8.1-r2058M/src” directory;
3. type ”make” to build the binaries.

and i followd this steps but this gives me errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D-ITG needs gcc GNU libraries that available to download in mingw package...
mingw contains a lot of libraries... first of all it needs to make command in prompt...
to this we need to download mingw and set bin folder path of mingw to system environment ....
i did this mistake that i'm downloaded an incomplete version of mingw ...
in D-ITG manual said download Dev-C++...when you install dev-C++ it has a mingw folder but when i installed it this folder has not that libraries...

Answer (score 0):

i got it running finally on Windows 7. I followed the following steps:

1. Unzip D-ITG-2.8.1-r1023-src.zip to C:\D-ITG-2.8.1-r1023
2. Download Dev-Cpp(4.9.9.2) with Mingw/GCC 3.4.2 from website 
   bloodshed.net/dev/devcpp.html
3. Install Dev-Cpp in 
          C:\Dev-Cpp
4. Run Dev-Cpp
5. Select Tools--> Compile Options-->Directories-->Binaries
   Add
          C:\Dev-Cpp\libexec\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2
6. From Dev-Cpp open project
          C:\D-ITG-2.8.1-R1023\src\D-ITG.dev
   Then open win-mingw.mk and uncomment the first three options as indicated in 
   the file.Change the path of Dev-Cpp installation to
          C:\Dev-Cpp
   Then press     Cntrl+F11
   All the binaries will be copied to 
          C:\D-ITG-2.8.1-r1023\bin
   Close Dev-Cpp
7. Start ITGRecv and ITGSend from cmd

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> apt-get install gcc